# ASP Classic, SOAP / XML Request and response

Tags: xml, soap, vbscript, asp-classic, xmlhttprequest

Fairly new to this so please bear with me.

i have been given this as a request

```
POST /weblordinterface/interface.asmx HTTP/1.1
Host: weblord-test.toshiba-tro.de
Content-Type: application/soap+xml; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: length

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap12:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap12="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope">
  <soap12:Body>
    <_getCaseById xmlns="http://weblord.toshiba-tro.de/">
      <sIdCase>string</sIdCase>
      <sUser>string</sUser>
      <sPassword>string</sPassword>
    </_getCaseById>
  </soap12:Body>
</soap12:Envelope>
```

from the servicve provider and this as a response

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: application/soap+xml; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: length

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap12:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap12="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope">
  <soap12:Body>
    <_getCaseByIdResponse xmlns="http://weblord.toshiba-tro.de/">
      <_getCaseByIdResult>xml</_getCaseByIdResult>
    </_getCaseByIdResponse>
  </soap12:Body>
</soap12:Envelope>
```

i have written an ASP page that has the IDcase / user / password forwarded to me and i know this part works as i can display all 3 onscreen.

my code is :-

```
<%

dim sUser 
dim sPassword
dim sIdCase

sIdCase=Request.QueryString("sIdCase")
sPassword=Request.QueryString("sPassword")
sUser=Request.QueryString("sUser")

Dim objXMLHTTP 
set objXMLHTTP = server.Createobject("MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP.3.0") 

Dim strRequest, strResult, 


strRequest ="<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?><soap12:Envelope xmlns:xsi='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance'  xmlns:xsd='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema'  xmlns:soap12='http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope'>" _
& "    <soap12:Body><_getCaseById xmlns='http://weblord.toshiba-tro.de/'><sIdCase>" & sIdCase & "</sIdCase>" _
& "            <sUser>" & sUser & "</sUser> <sPassword>" & sPassword & "</sPassword></_getCaseById></soap12:Body></soap12:Envelope>"
objXMLHTTP.open "POST", "http://weblord.toshiba-tro.de/weblordinterface/interface.asmx" , true
objXMLHTTP.setRequestHeader "User-Agent","HTTP/1.1"
objXMLHTTP.setRequestHeader "Host","weblord-test.toshiba-tro.de"
objXMLHTTP.setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "application/soap+xml; charset=utf-8"
objXMLHTTP.setRequestHeader "Content-Length", Len(strRequest)
'objXMLHTTP.setRequestHeader "SOAPAction", "http://weblord.toshiba-tro.de/"

objXMLHTTP.send(strRequest)


If objXMLHTTP.status = 200 Then
    TextResponse = objXMLHTTP.responseText
    XMLResponse = objXMLHTTP.responseXML
    StreamResponse = objXMLHTTP.responseStream
Else
    response.write("we have an error")
End If

Set objXMLHTTP = Nothing


%>
```

Can someone please enlighten me as to how i can get the response and display it, i seem to get an error at the

```
If objXMLHTTP.status = 200 Then
```

line of

> msxml3.dll error '8000000a'
>
> The data necessary to complete this operation is not yet available.

Can one of you experts please help

Answer (score 2):

You are specifying an asynchronous request when you open the connection. So the data is not yet available in the subsequent code. Change this to a synchronous request instead.

ie. change from this...

```
objXMLHTTP.open "POST", "http://weblord.toshiba-tro.de/weblordinterface/interface.asmx" , true
```

...to this...

```
objXMLHTTP.open "POST", "http://weblord.toshiba-tro.de/weblordinterface/interface.asmx" , false
```

Comment: Thanks John, i have tried both Async and snyc, with syn the status shows as 403.

Comment: It needs to be synchronous. 403 status is unauthorised, indicating that either the credentials you are connecting with are invalid, or the computer you are accessing from needs to be whitelisted.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out folks

Host: weblord-test.toshiba-tro.de

is what was given, i was posting to

objXMLHTTP.open "POST", "http://weblord.toshiba-tro.de/weblordinterface/interface.asmx"

Once i added -test in it now works.